# How to split string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

[image_file_txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcqkq.png)

I have 1 txt file like image. I want to split the above data with every 13 substrings 1 time. for python. For example:
[Click to images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMsjz.png)

Comment: What have you attemped? Try using a for loop and slicing

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. We will help you with issues you come across during your projects/challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List Comprehension.

```
text_input = 'TTTTTXXTTTXXTTXTTTXTTXTTTXTTTXXXXTTTXTTTTX'    
chunk_size=13
output=[text_input[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(text_input), chunk_size)]
print(output)
    
#This will output
['TTTTTXXTTTXXT', 'TXTTTXTTXTTTX', 'TTTXXXXTTTXTT', 'TTX']
```

Comment: Try not to shadow builtin names like `input`